# Send a class object returned to an Ajax call

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, class

My goal is to send a class object returned to an Ajax call in `Default.aspx`.

The `Default.aspx` sends a json string to [WebMethod]: `{ID:someid}`.

The connectionstring jsonobject defines jsondata.mdf.

jsondata.mdf contains columns: `idd, datetime, col1, col2` and `col3` with many rows of data.

Having a problem with the return line:

```
return json2.ToArray();
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetJSONdata(string ID)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jsonobject"].ConnectionString;
        string cmdStr = "SELECT ([idd],[datetime],[col1],[col2],[col3]) FROM [jsondata] WHERE [idd]=@idd;";
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idd", ID);
                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        dt = ds.Tables[0];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        List<dataclass> classdata = new List<dataclass>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            dataclass dc = new dataclass();
            dc.idd = Convert.ToString(dr["idd"]);
            dc.datetime = Convert.ToString(dr["datetime"]);
            dc.col1 = Convert.ToString(dr["col1"]);
            dc.col2 = Convert.ToString(dr["col2"]);
            dc.col3 = Convert.ToString(dr["col3"]);
            classdata.Add(dc);
        }
        return classdata.ToArray();
    }
```

class1.cs

```
public class dataclass
{
    public string idd { get; set; }
    public string datetime { get; set; }
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
    public string col3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem with that line? We aren't there to see the exception on your computer, so you need to take the initiative and tell us what the problem is. By the way, [WebMethod is no longer supported by Microsoft](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/more-reasons-to-not-use-asmx-services-in-new-code/), instead you should use [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) or [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Error code: Cannot implicitly convert type 'JSONwebmethod.dataclass[]' to 'string'

Comment: Now I'm confused, because you said the problem was with `return json2.ToArray()` but that line doesn't appear in your code. You need to make it clear *where* your exception occurs and *what* the exception is. Please edit your post to clear that up.

Comment: You're returning an array when your webmethod specifies a string. It looks like you want to be returning a JSON object. You need to JSON serialize your array prior to returning it in response.